# MYSQL Pod on minikube failing (mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mysql/data': No space left on device)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Friends,

I'm trying to deploy a mysql cluster on minikube using the helm chart of Bitnami. It's not working apparently because of lack of space since I'm getting the following error: **mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mysql/data': No space left on device**.

I am running minikube (version: v1.15.0) on a macOS with 500GB RAM, more than the half of it is still free. Any ideas about how could I solve this problem?

I ssh into the minikube environment and run df -h. This the result:

$ df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.4G  487M  3.0G  15% /
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G   18M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  176K  1.9G   1% /tmp
**/dev/vda1        17G   16G     0 100% /mnt/vda1**
```

It seems it minikube is really out of space. What can be done in this case?

Here the complete logs of my pod:

```
mysql 17:08:49.22 Welcome to the Bitnami mysql container
mysql 17:08:49.22 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql
mysql 17:08:49.22 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mysql/issues
mysql 17:08:49.23 
mysql 17:08:49.23 INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL setup **
mysql 17:08:49.24 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
mysql 17:08:49.24 INFO  ==> Initializing mysql database
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mysql/data': No space left on device
```

Answer (score 4):

`minikube stop && minikube delete` then

```
minikube start --disk-size 50000mb
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using Minikube on a MacOS, Minikube is virtualized. Thus even if you have space on your entire device, you need to allocate more space in the VM, as Abhijit previously mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, man! I am completely new to all this. Now I understood it.